# yii2 active record не выводит ничего в результате, когда обычный SQL дает результат

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Есть следующий запрос:

```
$partners = \common\models\Friends::find()
    ->where(['friends.user_id' => $user->id])
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'user', 'friends.friend_id = user.id')
    ->select('user.*')
    ->all();
```

Он полностью эквивалентен обычному SQL:

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `friends` 
  INNER JOIN `user` ON friends.friend_id = user.id 
  WHERE `friends`.`user_id`=24
```

Если я делаю второй запрос прямиком в БД, то результат выводится адекватно. Но дамп `$partners` дает пустой результат:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(common\models\Friends)#146 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Почему в yii я получаю отличный от SQL результат?

Comment: SQL запрос вам выведет данные, но полей таблицы friends в sql запросе нет. Я думаю, поэтому переменная $partners не имеет значения, т. к. yii разбирает поля которые в sql запросе и на основе этого создает массив объектов

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что должно быть как-то так

```
$partners = \common\models\Users::find()
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'friends', 'friends.friend_id = user.id')
    ->where(['friends.user_id' => $user->id])
    ->all();
```

А вообще, если я правильно понимаю, у пользователя вытаскивается его друзья, я думаю, лучше это засунуть в метод модели Users и организовать код через $this->hasMany